# How likely is it for an international student to be supported financially during their internship in Austria?

Tags: phd, internship, austria

I am a Master's student from Iran. I sent an email to a professor in Austria and asked for a PhD position. He said that he did not have any open position, but if I like, I can go there for an internship.
I want to know whether I will be supported financially or not
and how I can ask about it in such a way that does not cause any negative impact.

Comment: You can just ask him. It will not cause any negative impact.

Comment: You can ask but it's very unlikely that he will pay you. You could instead try to get funding for the visit. E.g. in Germany, DAAD would be an agency that offers such grants.

Comment: @Roland It is indeed unlikely that he will pay, but he WILL be able to help getting you funding. This help could be anywhere from sending a link to a website, to helping you write a proposal or fill in the application forms. This will depend on the person and the time they can spend on it.

Answer (score 7):

When it comes to funded research-related stays in Austria, the go-to-place is the officially curated database https://grants.at (of the OeAD, or the Austrian Exchange Agency).

It even offers granular search options. Here is an example of a search form (perhaps the option "*Practical trainings*" may be the right one for your case):

[image: A search form of the OeAD]